How to add extra column(first column) to my csv file in apache nifi
I have a scenario, that, i have one flow file with csv content as data with tab a column separator. Below is the flow file content
test.txt
`Key  value
123  AAA
456  BBB
789  CCC`

Now i would like to get my output as like below
`Header  key  value
A  123  AAA
A  456  BBB
A  789  CCC`

I have achieved it using replace text processor. But i would like to achieve it using either updateContent or UpdateAttribute or any of the controller services. Could you please help me. Below was the code snippet i have used.
I am expecting a new column should be added to my csv flow file

Use a QueryRecord processor
